# How to let users download a file with data stored in an array (CSV/Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, csv

How do I allow users to download an array that has stored a list of objects to a csv without using express or any additional libraries?

This is what I have tried but not sure what to stick infront of res.setHeader - and I want to try to prompt the user if they want to download it.

```
var filename = 'Music' + new Date() + '.csv';
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [http](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.10/api/http.html#response.setHeader) package that bundled with NodeJS

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 80,
  path: '/download',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment;filename=' + filename);
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

Comment: There seems to be an error with .setHeader not being a method